# Why am I getting a 'File not found' error while reading a DICOM image using Pydicom library in a Flask app?

Tags: python, flask, object-detection

I'm trying to run a Flask app for pneumonia detection using computer vision, in which I'm getting an error, 'File not found' after trying to upload a test dicom image.

I'm trying to implement an object detection application using Flask framework in which my index.html file looks like this: -

```
<html>
    <body>
        <h1>Pneumonia Detection</h1>
        Please upload the image in DICOM format here
        <form action="/sub" method="POST">
            <p>Input Image</p>
            <input type="file" name="input_image" placeholder="Input Image">
            <input type="submit">
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

And this is how my code in app.py file for reading the uploaded image file from index.html is: -

```
@app.route("/sub",methods = ["POST"]) 
def submit():
    if request.method == "POST":
        img = request.form["input_image"]
        img_data = dcm.read_file(img, force = True)
```

I get the following error, whenever I try to execute the Flask app on VS code and upload a test image file 'c1ec035b-377b-416c-a281-f868b7c9b6c3.dcm': -

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 2525, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1822, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1796, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\Capstone_GL\app.py", line 39, in submit
    img_data = dcm.read_file(img, force = True)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\Users\Lenovo\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\pydicom\filereader.py", line 993, in dcmread
    fp = open(fp, 'rb')
         ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'c1ec035b-377b-416c-a281-f868b7c9b6c3.dcm'
```

Can anybody please tell me what might be the reason behind this issue? And what's the workaround for this issue?

Comment: File uploads don't end in `request.form`, but in `request.files`

Answer (score 0):

As written in [docs](https://flask.palletsprojects.com/en/2.3.x/api/#flask.Request.form),

> Please keep in mind that file uploads will not end up here, but instead in the files attribute.

`request.form` doesn't contain file uploads. Use `request.files["input_image"]` instead.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response! I tried to use `request.files["input_image"]` instead of `request.form` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: @NinadMahajan  1. Try adding ``enctype="multipart/form-data"`` to the `<form>` 2. Try passing `request.files["input_image"].stream` instead. If all else fails, you can `save` the file using `request.files["input_image"].stream.save("C:\Users\Lenovo\HomeDirectory\file.dcm")` and then pass the full `"C:\Users\Lenovo\HomeDirectory\file.dcm"` to dicom